# back to top element remains in hover state on touch OS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a back-to-top element in place on a page, with a css to define it, an html to call it and a js to execute the element fade-in then the page scroll-up when clicked then the element fade-out.

On any desktop browser everything works fine. The problem is that on any touch device (iOS, Android, etc, and simulators too) after the first touch the element remains hilighted (I mean with hover settings) also after the fade-out, and it remains hilighted also when it disappears and when after the next scrolls it appears again.

This is the code:

```
<style>

#back2Top {
    width: 38px;
    line-height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 25px;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #ff8400;
    color: #006c8b;
    font-family: Digit;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px 0px 0px 5px; 
}

#back2Top:hover {
    background-color: #006c8b;
    color: #ff8400;
}

</style>

<a id="back2Top" href="#">m</a>

<script>

$(window).scroll(function() {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (height > 100) {
        $('#back2Top').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#back2Top').fadeOut();
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#back2Top").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
        return false;
    });
});

</script>
```

How can be a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `:hover` in a media query. This prevents triggering `:hover` on touch.

```
@media (hover: hover) {
    #back2Top:hover {
        background-color: #006c8b;
        color: #ff8400;
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work. Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2913ah76/1/

Comment: can't see your jsfiddle. On browsers it does not work. Neither on iOS nor on Android. Nope

Comment: I was careless... I left the css `#back2Top:hover { background-color: #006c8b; color: #ff8400;}` also outside of the media query. Removed, and now it works, So you were right, Sev.

Answer (score 0):

Tried to use a workaround, but it was not the original idea. Added this js code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#back2Top").mouseout(function(){
        $("#back2Top").css("background-color", "#ff8400");
        $("#back2Top").css("color", "#006c8b");
    });
});
```

Any comment is welcome.

And anyway, my workaround... doesn not work  :(